# Hide custom posts from certain taxonomy in rest api

Tags: rest-api, content-restriction

I have a custom post type called `books`, the books are available here:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/books
```

I have a custom taxonomy `books-category` and one of the category is `general`.

How can I hide all posts except the ones marked as general from rest api if the user is not logged in? So only if user is logged in, the rest api can populate posts with other categories.